# Rails 4 production.log stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a problem with my production.log file in Rais 4.

I have deleted the file after a Capistrano deploy, i created the file again but know is always 0kb. What can i do?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server? Your server loses its link to the log file after you removed it while it's writing to it.

Comment: I did already tried, it does not work anyway :(

Comment: Perhaps you created the file without permissions for the server to write to. Try touching the file as the user the server runs as, or removing it and restarting the server.

Comment: Thanks! now it works normally again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix it by restarting `nginx` and my app's `unicorn` instance:

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
$ sudo service unicorn_appname restart
```

If that doesn't work try `stop` and `start` instead of `restart`. You also need to make sure that the app has permissions to write to the file. `touch` the file as the user your app uses to run in the server.

Or:

```
$ chown username production.log
```

Comment: Just restart app server (e.g. Unicorn) will do.